# Twitter hash timeline in RSS

Tags: twitter, rss

I know to RSS a user feed, it's `https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.rss`

But what if instead I want to pull a hash?...what's the RSS URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=%23hashtag
```

Here `%23` = url encoded `#`. There are even [more parameters](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) other than query(`q`) you can try.